# How to meta program methods from a Class Constant array which is being referenced in a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I wrote a basic Eventable module that allows other Classes to create events for itself. All the Models have their own set of events such as a `Message` being `sent` or a `User` having a `sign_in` event. I would like to create an array of events as a constant at the class level and access that array inside the module to build helper methods for creating events like so:

```
class User
  EVENT_TYPES = ['sign_in', 'sign_out']
  include Eventable
end
```

---

```
class Message
  EVENT_TYPES = ['sent', 'opened']
  include Eventable
end
```

---

```
module Eventable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :events, as: :eventable
    attr_accessor :metadata

    self::EVENT_TYPES.each do |event_type|
      define_method "create_#{event_type}_event" do |args={}|
        Event.create(eventable: self, event_type: event_type)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The issue with this is: the methods are not being defined properly. It cannot reference the respective Model's constant `EVENT_TYPES` properly.

How can I access a class constant from insude a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using constant like that is not very rubyesque, I'd say. This is much more idiomatic (in rails, at least).

```
class Message
  include Eventable

  event_types :sent, :opened
end
```

And here's the implementation

```
module Eventable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def event_types(*names)
      names.each do |event_type|
        define_method "create_#{event_type}_event" do |args={}|
          Event.create(eventable: self, event_type: event_type)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Segio, may I ask about `Event` and `Event.create`? I am not very proficient in Rails, but I guess that these are brought about by `has_many :events` line. Could you point me to the page where this is documented?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: `Event` is, likely, an active record model (which has `create` method). `has_many` is a method in active record which defines methods like `events`, `event_ids` and others. Lots of info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, just to be completely sure, if `Event` class did not exist, `has_many :events` method would not construct it for us, would it?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: no, it wouldn't. On the contrary, it would raise an error, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Constants can be obtained by `Module#const_get` method. But I would not present the event types for individual classes as constants, but as either class methods or instance variables belonging to the class:

```
class User
  def self.event_types
    [:sign_in, :sign_out]
  end
end

# or

class User
  @event_types = [:sign_in, :sign_out]

  class << self
    attr_reader :event_types
  end
end
```

It seems that another answer expressed most of the remaining things I wanted to say. But one more thing: I would not name the module `Eventable`, but eg. `HavingEvents` or simply `Events`.

Comment: Thanks Boris, I wish I could accept two answers, as both are really effective.

Comment: Sergio's is better than mine anyway, +1 to him.